# EF Core Fluent API Configurations with Inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

EF CORE Fluent Api Configuration in separate files are Working fine with simple classes [Ref #1](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api) && [Ref # 2](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/move-configurations-to-seperate-class-in-code-first.aspx). The problem comes when entities are Inherited from `KeyedEntity` or `AuditableEntity`

```
class abstract KeyedEntity<TValue> {
      public TValue Id {get; set;}
}

class abstract  AuditableEntity<TValue> : KeyedEntityBase<TValue>{
      public DateTime DateCreated {get; set;}
      public DateTime DateModified {get; set;}
}
```

Mapper Goes Something like this

```
public class KeyedEntityMap<TEntity, TId>
    : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity> where TEntity
    : KeyedEntityBase<TId> where TId : struct
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder)
    {
        // Primary Key
        builder.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        builder.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("id").ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    }
}

public class AuditableEntityMap<TEntity, TId>
    : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>    where TEntity 
    : AuditableEntity<TId>    where TId : struct
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder)
    {
        // Properties
        builder.Property(t => t.DateCreated).HasColumnName("DateCreated");
        builder.Property(t => t.DateModified).HasColumnName("DateModified");           
    }
}
```

Now the Problem Occurs with the Entity that inherits from `AuditableEntity`. I need to register Map from that Particular Enitity class along with `AuditableEntityMap` class and `KeyedEntityMap` class.

Now I can either forget about Map Inheritance and merge all the complex inheritance Maps in the entity class, which I don't want to do and respect [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) . **The problem with complex inheritance is its not registering my entity maps**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several ways you can achieve DRY for base entity configuration.

Bit the closest to your current design is to simply follow the entity hierarchy in the configuration classes:

```
public class KeyedEntityMap<TEntity, TId> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>
    where TEntity : KeyedEntityBase<TId>
    where TId : struct
{
    public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder)
    //       ^^^
    {
        // Primary Key
        builder.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        builder.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("id").ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    }
}

public class AuditableEntityMap<TEntity, TId> : KeyedEntityMap<TEntity, TId>
    //                                                 ^^^
    where TEntity : AuditableEntity<TId>
    where TId : struct
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder)
    //       ^^^
    {
        base.Configure(builder); // <<<
        // Properties
        builder.Property(t => t.DateCreated).HasColumnName("DateCreated");
        builder.Property(t => t.DateModified).HasColumnName("DateModified");           
    }
}
```

and then for specific entity that needs additional configuration:

```
public class Person : AuditableEntity<int>    
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

you would register

```
public class PersonEntityMap : AuditableEntityMap<Person, int>
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Person> builder)
    {
        base.Configure(builder);
        // Properties
        builder.Property(t => t.Name).IsRequired();
        // etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: What if i want to configure properties depending on their struct type or even entityTypeBuilder type?

Comment: @liqSTAR Not sure what you mean by "their struct" type. Also entity type. Base entity means common properties which are one and the same, so is the builder for configuring them. If they are different, then they are not "base". Note that EF entity means real data model - needs real properties with real type, not abstract interfaces or other OOP stuff.

Comment: Okay let me describe it less complex. You allow struct as `TId`. I want  that a `Guid` generates value on add `ValueGeneratedOnAdd` but if it is a `int` I want use the  `UseIdentityColumn` method on it.

Comment: @liqSTAR This usually is done by convention. But you could always use conditional blocks inside the base configuration if you wish. e.g. `if (typeof(TId) == typeof(Guid)) builder.Property(t => t.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd(); else if (..) else ...` etc.

Comment: Omg so simple...i tried to use Metadata or something crazy.

Comment: @IvanStoev masterpiece!